# "Scrapyd-deploy -l" opens a file instead of running command in Windows

Tags: scrapyd

I'm trying to change my project from scrapy to scrapyd because my host provider told me it was easier to implement this way. However I'm finding the available documentation really confusing.

This are the steps I have followed so far:

Installed scrapyd, setuptools

On Power Shell I run the following command

`scrapyd`

This starts the server and I'm able to access `http://localhost:6800/`. Until then everything is fine. In my `scrapy.cfg` file I uncommented what's under `[deploy]`.

Problem is when I run `scrapyd-deploy -l` (as pointed out in [scrapyd-client's github page](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client)), instead of getting a list with available targets, it asks me to open a file in a text editor.

The file that opens is this:

[image: file that opens when running scrapyd-deploy -l]

This file also opens when I run scrapyd-deploy default. Or just scrapyd-deploy. I can't find anywhere information on this topic, and I'm having trouble understanding the documentation available at github, such as what should I use as target url when I move my project to my host? And what should be set as username and password.

I'm really sorry if this are basic questions, but I didn't know who else to ask. Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else is having this same problem, I was able to fix it. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but at least it worked. If anybody knows a better solution please feel free to answer and I'll check that as the accepted answer instead.

Basically I did what PaulTur did on [this issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client/issues/13) and copied the `scrapyd-deploy` file from `c:\python27\Scripts` directory to the directory of my project. And then succesfully ran:

`python scrapyd-deploy -l`

After that change I was able to run all the scrapyd-deploy commands through `python`and finally generated the .egg file.

Comment: Thanks for following up your question with your answer.  Your solution worked for me also but after installing scrapyd-deploy via `pip` I had to rename the scrapyd-deploy FILE to scrapyd-deploy.py then it would recognize in my windows command line.  When trying to run it, I also had to use the `.py` file extension for the command to work.